# Не работает ajax-запрос (Bitrix CMS)

Tags: ajax, битрикс

Всем привет. Задача вот какая:

Есть страница https://aecsd.org/test/
На ней размещена форма с несколькими выпадающими полями.
Ниже размещён компонент Битрикс:  bitrix:news.list - это компонент который выводит список новостей.
Я хочу сделать фильтрацию этого списка новостей например по Стране. Пользователь выбирает из выпадающего списка страну, и таблица оставляет только те строки, в которых страна совпадает с выбранным из списка значением.

Сейчас код вот так выглядит:

```html
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Title");
?>
<form  id="myform">

 <select name="PROPERTY_COMPANY" style="width: 100px;">
  <option value="Выберите страну">Выберите Компанию</option>
  <option value="National Securities Depository Limited">National Securities Depository Limited</option>
  <option value="National Settlement Depository">National Settlement Depository</option>
  <option value="Merkezi Kayıt Kuruluşu A.Ş.">Merkezi Kayıt Kuruluşu A.Ş.</option>
  <option value="TDCC Taiwan Depository &amp; Clearing Corporation">TDCC Taiwan Depository &amp; Clearing Corporation</option>
  <option value="Central Depository of Armenia">Central Depository of Armenia</option>
  <option value="CSDC (China Securities Depository and Clearing Corporation)">CSDC (China Securities Depository and Clearing Corporation)</option>
  <option value="Euroclear">Euroclear</option>
  <option value="KSD (Korean Securities Depository)">KSD (Korean Securities Depository)</option>
  <option value="SHCH (Shanghai Clearing House)">SHCH (Shanghai Clearing House)</option>
 </select>

 <select name="PROPERTY_COUNTRY">
  <option value="Выберите страну" data-filter>Выберите страну</option>
  <option value="India" data-filter >India</option>
  <option value="Russia" data-filter >Russia</option>
  <option value="Turkey" data-filter >Turkey</option>
  <option value="Taiwan" data-filter >Taiwan</option>
  <option value="Armenia" data-filter >Armenia</option>
  <option value="China" data-filter >China</option>
  <option value="Belgium" data-filter >Belgium</option>
  <option value="Korea" data-filter >Korea</option>
  <option value="Korea" data-filter >Korea</option>
 </select>

<input type="date" name="PROPERTY_DATE_FROM">
<input type="date" name="PROPERTY_DATE_TO">


 <select name="PROPERTY_SUBJECT" style="width: 140px;">
  <option value="Выберите тему">Выберите тему</option>
  <option value="E-Voting System of NSDL (Video)">E-Voting System of NSDL (Video)</option>
  <option value="E-Voting System of NSDL (Presentation)">E-Voting System of NSDL (Presentation)</option>
  <option value="Creating the E-Voting System for Shareholder Meetings in Russia (Article)">Creating the E-Voting System for Shareholder Meetings in Russia (Article)</option>
  <option value="E-voting System (Presentation)">E-voting System (Presentation)</option>
  <option value="Electronic General Meeting (e-GEM)">Electronic General Meeting (e-GEM)</option>
  <option value="Public Disclosure Platform (PDP)">Public Disclosure Platform (PDP)</option>
  <option value="Implementation of Non-Custody Services">Implementation of Non-Custody Services</option>
  <option value="E-Voting Opportunities">E-Voting Opportunities</option>
  <option value="FinTech and Cyber Resilience (Presentation, WFC Board, May 2017)">FinTech and Cyber Resilience (Presentation, WFC Board, May 2017)</option>
  <option value="Better Corporate Governance With E-voting Gradually Gets Adopted in Taiwan. -a Big Data Analysis of Taiwan’s E-voting in AGMs">Better Corporate Governance With E-voting Gradually Gets Adopted in Taiwan. -a Big Data Analysis of Taiwan’s E-voting in AGMs</option>
  <option value="Cash accounts &amp; New opportunities">Cash accounts &amp; New opportunities</option>
  <option value="Government bonds for individuals">Government bonds for individuals</option>
  <option value="Legal Risk Management for Stock Connect">Legal Risk Management for Stock Connect</option>
  <option value="Cross-border links challenges">Cross-border links challenges</option>
  <option value="CSDs’ role in Implementing Cross-border investments">CSDs’ role in Implementing Cross-border investments</option>
  <option value="China Bond Market">China Bond Market</option>
 </select>
</form>

<?
 var_dump($_GET['PROPERTY_COUNTRY']);
 $GLOBALS['filter_ex'] = array('PROPERTY_COUNTRY' => $_GET['PROPERTY_COUNTRY']);//фильтруем по стране
?>

<?
 if($_REQUEST['ajax']){
  $APPLICATION->RestartBuffer();
 }
?>


 <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
 "bitrix:news.list", 
 "pdf_list", 
 array(
  "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "pdf_list",
  "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "ru",
  "IBLOCK_ID" => "54",
  "NEWS_COUNT" => "20",
  "SORT_BY1" => "ACTIVE_FROM",
  "SORT_ORDER1" => "DESC",
  "SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
  "SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
  "FILTER_NAME" => "filter_ex",
  "FIELD_CODE" => array(
   0 => "",
   1 => "",
  ),
  "PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
   0 => "",
   1 => "",
  ),
  "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
  "DETAIL_URL" => "",
  "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
  "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
  "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
  "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
  "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
  "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
  "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
  "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
  "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
  "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
  "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
  "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
  "SET_BROWSER_TITLE" => "Y",
  "SET_META_KEYWORDS" => "Y",
  "SET_META_DESCRIPTION" => "Y",
  "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
  "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "Y",
  "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y",
  "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "N",
  "PARENT_SECTION" => "",
  "PARENT_SECTION_CODE" => "",
  "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
  "STRICT_SECTION_CHECK" => "N",
  "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
  "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
  "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
  "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
  "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
  "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
  "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
  "PAGER_TITLE" => "Новости",
  "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
  "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
  "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
  "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
  "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
  "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
  "SHOW_404" => "N",
  "MESSAGE_404" => ""
 ),
 false
);?>


<?
 if($_REQUEST['ajax']){
  die();
 }
?>


<script>

 $(document)
 .on('change', '[name="PROPERTY_COUNTRY"]', function() {
   $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit')
 })
 .on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('test');

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://aecsd.org/test?ajax=Y',
    data: 'PROPERTY_COUNTRY=' + $('select[name="PROPERTY_COUNTRY"] option:selected').val(),
    success: function(msg){
    console.log('success');
     },
     error: function(msg){
     console.log('error');
     }
  });


 });


</script>

<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

Но при выборе страны из выпадающего списка, в $_GET-параметр ничего не добавляется, а мне нужно, чтобы добавлялось PROPERTY_COUNTRY=Russia к примеру.
Помогите пожалуйста, скажите, что я делаю не так?

Хотел сделать без перезагрузки страницы, поэтому и использовал ajax-запрос.

Answer (score 0):

сам компонент новостей вынести в отдельный php файл с подключенной служебной частью пролога. В этом файле перед выводом компонента проверять $GET[PROPERTY_COUNTRY] и подставлять его в фильтр компонента новостей

в исходном файле код вызова компонента удалить и вместо него вставить 
блок к примеру с id = "#obertka-novostey"

вместо

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'https://aecsd.org/test?ajax=Y',
      data: 'PROPERTY_COUNTRY=' + $('select[name="PROPERTY_COUNTRY"] option:selected').val(),
      success: function(msg){
         console.log('success');
       },
       error: function(msg){
          console.log('error');
       }
    });
```

надо

```
$.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: 'https://aecsd.org/путь к файлу с компонентом.php?PROPERTY_COUNTRY=' + $('select[name="PROPERTY_COUNTRY"] option:selected').val(),
          data: '',
          success: function(msg){
             console.log(msg);
             $('#obertka-novostey').html(msg);

           },
           error: function(msg){
              console.log('error');
              $('#obertka-novostey').html("Ошибка загрузки новостей!");
           }
        });
```